# Этимология слова "Орда"

Tags: этимология

Есть 2 версии: тюркская `орда` - лагерь и латинская `ordo` порядок.

Как вы считаете?

Comment: Бармалей, вы серьезно?
Ну какое ж оно, к черту, "латинское"?
К тому же, что это за форма для латыни? 
порядок - ordinem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Орда - стан, кочевье; ханский дворец. 
Однозначно - тюркское или монгольское (разделить, видимо, не удастся, как и в случае с "богатырем").

Comment: Ну почему же не получится - в тюркском орда слово "пустое" - то есть не имеющее какого-то своего начального смысла, так что слово я думаю монгольских корней

Answer (score 0):

В общетюркском языке слово «Орта / Орда / Орду» означает «центр, порядок», следовательно, оно использовалось для обозначения «Государства». Тюркские слова «Юрта / Юрт» также произошли отсюда.
Слова «orтh-os», «or-do» и «hor-de» в индоевропейских языках также использовались в том же и схожих значениях.

Answer (score -1):

Мне кажется всё проще. Не надо ходить за три девять земель. В мордовском языке есть слово "Арды" - означает быструю езду, движение (конница). Если назвать слово на русский манер, получится "орды" - стремительно движущаяся конница.